# How to do disable the confirmation on the "remote control" option of RDP?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-control, windows-server-2012-r2

On a Windows server, when in a session via RDP, I want to do "remote control" to a second session opened by a different administrator. 
How can make this option to connect without prompting the user to confirm? 
e.g. when he's out for lunch and I need to handle something running on his session.

What I'm after is to configure the server to automatically confirm the remote control operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself:

*Start* --> *Administrative Tools* --> *Remote Desktop Services* --> *Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration*

and then in the "remote control" tab selected "Use remote control with the following settings" and unmark the checkbox defaultly stating "***Require user's permission***".

But on second thought, it's only advisable (if at all) when you have total confidence in your administrator, since in this way he can of course perform tasks the other administrator does not approve of.